# Stationing ajax loading image on the center of a page

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

Stationing ajax loading image on the center of a page.

Am using the above code to load database record via ajax by referencing the loading image in Div element above

my question is how can i make this loading image to appear at the center of the mobile page may be by way of some css or any 
other means
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

//setInterval(function(){


$('#loan').fadeIn(400).html('<img width="60" height="60" src="load.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Data....Please Wait</span>');

 $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
url:'load.php',
data:"uname="+uname,
 success:function(data){
 $('#bring_data').html(data); 
$('#load_spin').hide();
} }) 

//}, 10000); 


});


</script>


<div id="load_spin"></div>
```

Comment: how about position:absolute;top:50%;left:40%;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS for that.

```
#load_spin {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%,
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Provided the parent element of `#load_spin` is relatively positioned, the above CSS will make sure that the element with the id `load_spin` is horizontally and vertically centered within this container.

Comment: If your question was ansered to your satisfaction, please mark the respective response as the correct answer or vote it up, if you can or like to.

Answer (score 0):

The way to center an image: make it into block of its own and apply the margin properties to it.

For example:

<--CSS FILE-->

```css
img.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<img class="displayed" src="file.jpg" alt="file">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: For the uppercase HTML-tag I would vote this answer down, if I could. Besides, your CS only centers the Image horizonally, and I am not sure if that is what the OP is striving for, exactly.